# App service logs not turning off after 12 hours

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When turning on "Application logging (filesystem)" the tooltip hint says it will turn itself off automatically in 12 hours. From what i see, that sometimes happens but sometimes it stays on for days. I could recognize no pattern when&how it happens.

Could anyone clarify what is expected behavior here, did something with the settings change (but portal info doesn't reflect the change)?...

Comment: The reason why this is disabled after 12 hours has to do with the limited set of storage you have on the local file system, which will be 1GB - 250GB depending on your App Service Plan (size). Maybe your service plan size is large?

Comment: @JoyWang its not large. Simple B1 instance. Although, now when you mention it, i did set limits for both, log size Quota and Retention period. Its set in a way that my logs never go anywhere near limits. Are you saying that if there is enough room in file system for logs that it overrides 12 hours automatic turn off feature? If so, do you maybe have some reference in docs mentioning it? tnx

Comment: Yes, I mean that. But I am not sure and also could not find the official doc mentions that. I can only find a SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903124/9455659), you could take a look.

Comment: @JoyWang yes, if that's the case then it would be good to have that somewhere in docs. I'll send a question to azure team and see what they say. will post an answer here when i get it. thanks for your link & help. You can put it in answer so i can upvote it and potentially confirm once i get response from azure team.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903124/9455659):

> The reason why this is disabled after 12 hours has to do with the limited set of storage you have on the local file system, which will be 1GB - 250GB depending on your App Service Plan (size).

Maybe there is enough space for logs in the file system that  it overrides 12 hours automatic turn off feature.(I am not 100% sure it is correct, if not, please correct me.)